# Regular expression to accept only characters (a-z) in a textbox

Tags: regex

What is a regular expression that accepts only characters ranging from a to z?

Comment: Sorry Actaully i have a text box,which should accept only strings with characters ranging from a to z

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regular Expression to match only alphabetic characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6067592/regular-expression-to-match-only-alphabetic-characters)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The pattern itself would be `[a-z]` for single character and `^[a-z]+$` for entire line. If you want to allow uppercase as well, make it `[a-zA-Z]` or `^[a-zA-Z]+$`

Comment: why have you used `+` sign before `$` sign in the last syntax.?

Comment: Sorry, I missed the `+` in the first one. The `+` sign means "1 or more"

Comment: this actually wont stop users to enter numbers or symbols in text box.this makes the input box invalid. is there anyway to prevent users not to enter numbers & symbols..etc except strrings?

Comment: In c#, it doesn't work new Regex(@"^[a-zA-Z]+$").Match("This is a long string").Value what is wrong with it.

Answer (score 13):

Try this to allow both lower and uppercase letters in A-Z:

```
/^[a-zA-Z]+$/
```

Remember that not all countries use only the letters A-Z in their alphabet. Whether that is an issue or not for you depends on your needs. You may also want to consider if you wish to allow whitespace (`\s`).

Comment: Sorry Actaully i have a text box,which should accept only strings with characters ranging from a to z

Comment: +1 for `Remember that not all countries use only the letters A-Z in their alphabet.`

Answer (score 4):

Allowing only character and space in between words :

> ^[a-zA-Z_ ]*$

[Regular Expression Library](http://regexlib.com/Search.aspx?k=alphabets&c=-1&m=-1&ps=20&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1)

Answer (score 3):

^[A-Za-z]+$
To understand how to use it in a function to validate text, see this [example](https://bugs.code.blog/2019/04/10/function-to-validate-name-for-numbers-and-special-characters/)

Answer (score 1):

None of the answers exclude special characters... Here is regex to ONLY allow letters, lowercase and uppercase.

```
/^[_A-zA-Z]*((-|\s)*[_A-zA-Z])*$/g
```

And as for different languages, you can use this function to convert letters to english letters before the check, just replace returnString.replace() with letters you need.

```
export function convertString(phrase: string) {
    var maxLength = 100;

    var returnString = phrase.toLowerCase();
    //Convert Characters
    returnString = returnString.replace("ą", "a");
    returnString = returnString.replace("č", "c");
    returnString = returnString.replace("ę", "e");
    returnString = returnString.replace("ė", "e");
    returnString = returnString.replace("į", "i");
    returnString = returnString.replace("š", "s");
    returnString = returnString.replace("ų", "u");
    returnString = returnString.replace("ū", "u");
    returnString = returnString.replace("ž", "z");

    // if there are other invalid chars, convert them into blank spaces
    returnString = returnString.replace(/[^a-z0-9\s-]/g, "");
    // convert multiple spaces and hyphens into one space
    returnString = returnString.replace(/[\s-]+/g, " ");
    // trims current string
    returnString = returnString.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");
    // cuts string (if too long)
    if (returnString.length > maxLength) returnString = returnString.substring(0, maxLength);
    // add hyphens
    returnString = returnString.replace(/\s/g, "-");

    return returnString;
}
```

Usage:

```
const firstName = convertString(values.firstName);

            if (!firstName.match(allowLettersOnly)) {
            }
```

Comment: *"None of the answers exclude special characters..."*: yours too: `/^[_A-zA-Z]*((-|\s)*[_A-zA-Z])*$/.test(']\[[]')` returns `true`. Also, `"ąąą".replace("ą", "a");` returns `"aąą"` (when the first parameter of `String.prototype.replace` is a string, only one occurrence is replaced, not all).

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
^[a-zA-Z]$
```

and browse for more at *[Expressions in category: Strings](http://regexlib.com/DisplayPatterns.aspx?cattabindex=3&categoryId=4)*.

Comment: This allows only one character.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this plugin for masking input...you can also check out the demo and use this plugin if this is what you may want...

[Masked Input Plugin](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/)

As you can see in the demonstration that you can use both alphatbets and numbers in a combination for complex textbox validations where an user might want to type not only alphatbets(azAZ) but also with numbers too(ie. alphanumberics)...specific validations like accepting only numbers in particular format(eg.phone numbers) can be done...that is the case when you can use this plugin for different circumstances..

hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

Just for people using bash shell, instead of "+" use "*"

"^[a-zA-Z]*$"

Comment: Good point, however this should be a comment or an edit (which i realize you cannot do with your rep)

Answer (score 0):

Match any word that contains any character in this group: [a-zA-Z0-9_]

```
/^[\w]+$/
```

Eg.

Match: `abcz`, `AbcZ`, `abc_1`, `AbC_1`

No match: `abc z` `abc-z` `Abc-z` `AbC-9` `aBc,12`