# Extract first integer in a string with PHP

Tags: php, preg-replace

Consider the following strings:

```
$strings = array(
    "8.-10. stage",
    "8. stage"
);
```

I would like to extract the first integer of each string, so it would return

```
8
8
```

I tried to filter out numbers with preg_replace but it returns all integers and I only want the first.

```
foreach($strings as $string)
{
    echo preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", '',$string);
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

A convenient (although not record-breaking in performance) solution using regular expressions would be:

```
$string = "3rd time's a charm";

$filteredNumbers = array_filter(preg_split("/\D+/", $string));
$firstOccurence = reset($filteredNumbers);
echo $firstOccurence; // 3
```

Assuming that there is at least one number in the input, this is going to print the first one.

Non-digit characters will be completely ignored apart from the fact that they are considered to delimit numbers, which means that the first number can occur at any place inside the input (not necessarily at the beginning).

If you want to only consider a number that occurs at the beginning of the string, regex is not necessary:

```
echo substr($string, 0, strspn($string, "0123456789"));
```

Comment: the "reset" example results in PHP Strict Notices... "Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference"

Comment: How can I do this if I only want to return the alphabet?

Comment: @xjshiya check out this answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6067592/regular-expression-to-match-only-alphabetic-characters/6067604

Comment: I would never use this in a professional application or anywhere else for that matter.  `array_filter` will destriy a zero value and this task can be done in one function call instead of 3.

Answer (score 9):

```
preg_match('/\d+/',$id,$matches);
$id=$matches[0];
```

Answer (score 8):

If the integer is always at the start of the string:

```
(int) $string;
```

If not, then [strpbrk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpbrk.php) is useful for extracting the first non-negative number:

```
(int) strpbrk($string, "0123456789");
```

#### Alternatives

These one-liners are based on [preg_split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php), [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) and [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php):

```
preg_split("/\D+/", " $string")[1];
(int) preg_replace("/^\D+/", "", $string);
preg_match('/\d+/', "$string 0", $m)[0];
```

Two of these append extra character(s) to the string so empty strings or strings without numbers do not cause problems.

Note that these alternative solutions are for extracting *non-negative* integers only.

Comment: `(int) $string;` is a lovely solution, I've never come across that

Comment: @mickmackusa, thanks for your review. The `preg_split` based solution had the additional space at the wrong side. Now corrected. The `strpbrk` solution is fine though: it was never intended to work without the `(int)` cast, so you should keep it in.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$strings = array(
    "8.-10. stage",
    "8. stage"
);

$res   = array();
foreach($strings as $key=>$string){
  preg_match('/^(?P<number>\d)/',$string,$match);
  $res[$key] = $match['number'];
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($res);
```

Comment: But only works for numbers with one digit at the start of the string, and if there is none, the line after causes an error.

Comment: The named capture group is needless pattern bloat because you are using the fullstring match anyway.  As trincot said, this will ONLY work when the number is at the start of the string.

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($strings as $string){
 if(preg_match("/^(\d+?)/",$string,$res)) {
   echo $res[1].PHP_EOL;
 }
}
```

Comment: The capture group is not necessary/beneficial. The lazy quantifier is not necessary/beneficial. This answer is missing its educational explanation.

Answer (score 1):

**if you have Notice in PHP 7 +**

> Notice:  Only variables should be passed by reference in YOUR_DIRECTORY_FILE.php on line LINE_NUMBER

**By using this code**

```
echo reset(array_filter(preg_split("/\D+/", $string)));
```

**Change code to**

```
$var = array_filter(preg_split("/\D+/", $string));
return reset($var);
```

*And enjoy! Best Regards Ovasapov*

Comment: `array_filter()` will destroy 0 values.

Answer (score 1):

**How to filter out all characters except for the first occurring whole integer:**

It is possible that the target integer is not at the start of the string (even if the OP's question only provides samples that start with an integer -- other researchers are likely to require more utility ...like the pages that I closed today using this page). It is also possible that the input contains no integers, or no leading / no trailing non-numeric characters.

The following is a regex expression has two checks:

1. It targets all non-numeric characters from the start of the string -- it stops immediately before the first encountered digit, if there is one at all.
2. It matches/consumes the first encountered whole integer, then immediatelly forgets/releases it (using `\K`) before matching/consuming ANY encountered characters in the remainder of the string.

My snippet will make 0, 1, or 2 replacements depending on the quality of the string.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/hABgk))

```
$strings = [
    'stage', // expect empty string
    '8.-10. stage', // expect 8
    '8. stage', // expect 8
    '8.-10. stage 1st', // expect 8
    'Test 8. stage 2020', // expect 8
    'Test 8.-10. stage - 2020 test', // expect 8
    'A1B2C3D4D5E6F7G8', // expect 1
    '1000', // expect 1000
    'Test 2020', // expect 2020
];

var_export(
    preg_replace('/^\D+|\d+\K.*/', '', $strings)
);
```

Or: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/YhXdB))

```
preg_replace('/^\D*(\d+).*/', '$1', $strings)
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => '',
  1 => '8',
  2 => '8',
  3 => '8',
  4 => '8',
  5 => '8',
  6 => '1',
  7 => '1000',
  8 => '2020',
)
```