# javascript for checking alphabets from a string

Tags: javascript

I have a string which is of format 245545g65.

```
var value = "245545g65"  
var last3Letters = value.substring(7,9);  // abc
```

Now I want to validate whether the last three letters contains only alphabets, if it is       alphabet , i want to alert it.how to alert g?

how do i do this?

Comment: I'd imagine you'll need a regex for this.

Comment: what do you mean by `alphabets` only word characters?

Comment: "only alphabets". You mean the letters a-z?

Comment: How does your example substring give a result of `abc`?

Comment: i only want characters from string and that to only from last three letter, not any numbers

Comment: i mean any letters from a-z

Comment: I believe you want something like this: http://regexr.com?35dsb

Answer (score 5, accepted):

assuming that "contains only alphabets" means the last three characters are a combination of the letters a-z:

```
var str = '245545g65';
if (/[a-z]{3}$/.test(str)){
  // last three characters are any combinations of the letters a-z
  alert('Only letters at the end!');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `isNaN` to check weather s string is number

```
if (!isNan(last3Letters))
    alert(last3Letters + ' is number.')
else
    alert(last3Letters + ' is not number.')
```

Comment: The non-numeric character may not be in the last 3 characters of the string.

Comment: So if `isNaN()` is `true`, it's a number??

Comment: @David- but he's checking the last 3 characters right?@CrazyTrain - missing !, thanks for pointing that out, I've edited my answer.

Comment: Trouble is that this only guarantees that it can't be converted to a number, not that it has all letters. For example `"q5A"` will fall into the category of "not a number", but it still has a number. OP wants to guarantee 3 letters.

Answer (score 0):

Easy:

```
var alpha = /^[A-z]+$/;
alpha.test(last3Letters);
```

This will return a boolean (true/false). [Stolen from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6067592/regular-expression-to-match-only-alphabetic-characters).

Comment: How will this work in his example with a g then 2 numbers?  Also, this would work with just 1 or 2 letters at the end.

Comment: @DavidStarkey: This answer is testing the last 3 characters, and is anchored to the start and end of that substring. It'll only pass if there are all letters.

Answer (score 0):

you can use RegEx and compare length

```
var re = new RegExp("[^0-9]*", "g");
var newlast3Letters =last3Letters.replace(re,"");
if(newlast3Letters.length!=last3Letters.length)
{
 alert("not all alphabets");
}
else
{
 alert("all alphabets");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this:

```
var value = "245545g65"  
if(value.slice(value.length-3).search(/[^a-z]/) < 0) {
    alert("Just alphabets");
} else {
    alert("Not just alphabets");
}
```