# How do I force input to be string only?

Tags: powershell, powershell-ise

I need the user to input a title of a book.

I need to make sure they input string only.

This is where I'm at so far, any guidance please.

Do { $strTitle = Read-host "Enter the book title"}
while ($strTitle -eq "")

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by string? alpha characters only?

You could try a regular expressions.

[Regular Expression to match only alphabetic characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6067592/regular-expression-to-match-only-alphabetic-characters)

http://powershell.com/cs/blogs/tobias/archive/2011/10/27/regular-expressions-are-your-friend-part-1.aspx

Answer (score 0):

#### Code to check for alpha characters:

```
Do {
    $strTitle = Read-host "Enter the book title"
} until ($strTitle -notMatch "[^[:alpha:]]")
```

Comment: I used this method but I was stuck in an endless loop. I wanted to setup more of a regular expressions, just don't understand the setup so far I have - [regex]$RstrTitle = “^[a-z]$”

Comment: Woops, sorry, The loop should actually be a `do {} until ()` loop, not `while`. That was why it was looping forever.

Comment: The only two output types from this command are String and SecureString (according to the help on Read-Host).  And you only get SecureString if you specify `-AsSecureString`.

Comment: I've changed the code so that it expects only alpha characters using the POSIX class `[:alpha:]`