# Regular Expression Annotation Fails Despite Being Correct

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-core-mvc

In my model I have the following:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "First name is required.")]
[Display(Name = "First Name")]
[MaxLength(50)]
[RegularExpression(@"/^[A-z]+$/", ErrorMessage = "Only alphabet characters are allowed.")]
public string FirstName { get; set; }
```

In the form it's failing the check no matter what I put in there. I want it to just make sure there are only letters, no numbers or special characters.

This is not a duplicate because the referenced post has nothing to do with data annotations. They're two different contexts.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex to match only letters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3617797/regex-to-match-only-letters)

Comment: While the solutions are the same problems differ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the regex delimiters (that are not used in .NET regex and are thus treated as literal slashes) and replace `A-z` with `A-Za-z` (see [Why is this regex allowing a caret?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29771926/3832970)).

Use

```
@"^[A-Za-z]+$"
```

Comment: [Regular Expression to match only alphabetic characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6067592/regular-expression-to-match-only-alphabetic-characters)

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy: The accepted answer [there](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6067592/regular-expression-to-match-only-alphabetic-characters) is wrong. Besides, the `/.../` is a common regex  writing form, in .NET, the `/` are parsed as literal symbols in the pattern.

Comment: Hmmm.. need to check

Comment: yep, I believe `/.../` is what really causing the problem in this case :)

Comment: And `[A-z]` will cause another problem if OP does not use my suggestion.

Comment: Also note `"(?i)^[a-z]+$"` would work (adds the case insensitive flag), or if you want to support languages other than English, `"^\p{L}+$"`.

Comment: I always use a-zA-Z pattern :) Now checked ASCII table and see that there is [ ] ^ between two ranges.

Comment: @p.s.w.g: To support Uncode, it should be `@"^\p{L}+$"` and to also support diacritics, `@"^[\p{L}\p{M}]+$"`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Woops yes, I forgot that slash