# Why does this regex not match numbers and single letters?

Tags: ruby, regex

Why does this regex not match `3a`?

```
(\/\d{1,4}?|\d{1,4}?|\d{1,4}[A-z]{1})
```

Using `\d{1,4}\D{1}`, the result is the same.

Streets numbers:

```
/1
78
3a
89/
-1 (special case)
1
```

https://regex101.com/r/cYCafR/3

Comment: Because `\d{1,4}?` matches them and `\d{1,4}[A-z]{1}` does not even have a chance to step in. Besides, `[A-z]` is a typo, it should be `[A-Za-z]`. It seems you want [`\d{1,4}[A-Za-z]|\/?\d{1,4}`](https://regex101.com/r/tdzSc5/1). Well, if it should be at the start of a line, [`^(?:\d{1,4}[A-Za-z]|\/?\d{1,4})`](https://regex101.com/r/tdzSc5/2).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The digits+letter combination is not matched due to the order of alternatives in your pattern. The `\d{1,4}?` matches the digit before the letter, and `\d{1,4}[A-z]{1}` does not even have a chance to step in.  See the [**Remember That The Regex Engine Is Eager**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html#eager) article.

The `\/\d{1,4}?` will match a `/` and a single digit after the slash, and `\d{1,4}?` will always match a single digit, as `{min,max}?` is a *lazy* range/interval/limiting quantifier and as such only matches as few chars as possible. See [**Laziness Instead of Greediness**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#lazy).

Besides, [`[A-z]` is a typo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29771901/why-is-this-regex-allowing-a-caret/29771926#29771926), it should be `[A-Za-z]`.

It seems you want

```
\d{1,4}[A-Za-z]|\/?\d{1,4}
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tdzSc5/1). If it should be at the start of a line, use

```
 ^(?:\d{1,4}[A-Za-z]|\/?\d{1,4})
```

See this [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tdzSc5/2).

**Details**

- `^` - start of a line
- `(?:` - start of a [non-capturing group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-what-does-do)

  - `\d{1,4}[A-Za-z]` - 1 to 4 digits and an ASCII letter
  - `|` - or
  - `\/?` - an optional `/`
  - `\d{1,4}` - 1 to 4 digits
- `)` - end of the group.

Comment: Actually A-z is from one street address regex from stack overflow some user example. I do not have time to search it again but, thank you for your time and useful links!

Comment: @MysteriousNothing That is a very common typo, it is even present in some regex tutorials online. There is only one environment, where `[A-z]` will work as expected, but it is certainly not Ruby.

Comment: @MysteriousNothing Lots of code contains mistakes. Just because you found the code somewhere on the internet, that doesn't make it right ;)

Comment: @TomLord But, but, it was on stack overflow and up voted :D [A-z] part was on there, other is my own stupidity.

Comment: @MysteriousNothing You must be talking about [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6067606/3832970). Read the **Update**. Although rather than writing something below that subtitle the user who posted the answer should have updated the solution at the top.

Answer (score 1):

Your regex uses lazy quantifiers like `{1,4}?`. These will match one character, and stop, because the rest of the pattern (i.e. nothing) matches the rest of the string. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301285/what-do-lazy-and-greedy-mean-in-the-context-of-regular-expressions) for how greedy vs lazy quantifiers work.

Another reason is that you put the `\d{1,4}[A-z]{1}` case *last*. This case will only be tried if the first two cases don't match. With `3a`, the `3` already matches the second case, so the last case won't be considered.

You seem to just want:

```
^(\d{1,4}[A-Za-z]|\/?\d{1,4})
```

Note how the `\/\d{1,4}` case and the `\d{1,4}` case in your original regex are combined into one case `\/?\d{1,4}`.

Comment: I have so much to learn, helpful articles for beginner like me, really thank you taking your time!

Comment: @MysteriousNothing If you think the answers answer your question, please consider selecting the answer that you think is the best and accept it by clicking on that checkmark!

Comment: both answers was helpful and tips and had useful tips so I select who posted first. I hope no hard feelings. :)

Comment: Mysterious, I have no comment on your selection for awarding the greenie, but I see no reason that an answer's timestamp should have anything to do with it. If you were asked which of two pizzas you preferred would the tie-breaker be the one you ate first?