# API configure parameters in url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I have created an API and i get all my data with a specific url, and by 'id' like this :

```
'myfolder.php/1'
```

So now i try to get my url with a string :

```
myfolder.php/mystring
```

in a Htacess for the id i do like this :

```
RewriteRule ^[^/]+/(\d+)$ myfolder.php?id=$1
```

but i don't find the good regex for characters i have try like this :

```
RewriteRule ^[^/]+/([a-z]+)$ myfolder.php?string
```

Edit :
If i call url `'myurl.com'`, my function getProducts is called.
If i call `'myurl.com/1'`, getProduct($id) is called
But if i call `'myurl.com/string'`, $_GET is empty, and getProducts is called.

```
   switch($request_method) {

        case 'GET':
            // HERE $_GET is empty if i called a string
            if(!empty($_GET["id"])) {
                $id= $_GET["id"];
                getProduct($id);
            }
            else {
                getProducts();
            }
            break;
        default:
            header("HTTP/1.0 405 Method Not Allowed");
            break;
    }
```

Comment: So what is the problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regular Expression to match only alphabetic characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6067592/regular-expression-to-match-only-alphabetic-characters)

Comment: Could you please do mention sample URL which you want to rewrite?

Comment: The problem is my rewriteRule is wrong for string. i have look topic and try like this RewriteRule ^[^/]+/^[A-Za-z]+$ myfolder.php?sign=i but that dosnt work too.

Comment: for the url : myurl.com/mystring, i would like something like that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your shown samples, please try following. Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs. Also make sure your php file is residing in same folder where you are keeping your htaccess rules file.

```
##Enabling RewriteEngine here.
RewriteEngine ON
##Placing conditions for non-existing requests with rewriterule to php file.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$  myfolder.php/$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

Comment: i just tried this, but always doesnt work. I have clear my browser cache before

Comment: @Ygg69, could you please do let me know sample/example url which you are hitting? And what is the error you are getting when you hit it?

Comment: @Ygg69, try changing last rule TO `RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$  myfolder.php/$1 [NC,QSA,L]` once and try again? Please make sure to clear browser cache before testing.

Comment: Just trying this, my $_GET return always an empty array

Comment: @Ygg69, ok when you hit url in browser what happens?

Comment: I have all my data, cause in my switch $_GET is empty, and so getProducts() is called, and not getProduct()

Comment: its ok, the problem was i don't have delete the rewrite rule for the id ... Your rewriterule work fine :) thank you

Comment: @Ygg69, Your welcome, cheers and happy learning.