# How can I limit my entry box input to alphabet only? tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

How can I restrict my entry box input to alphabet only?
I've tried many methods from online but nothing seemed to work . . .

This was the approach I thought of:

```py
window = Tk()

entry1 = Entry(window)
entry1.pack()

def submit():
    getinput = entry1.get()

    try:
        getinput != int(getinput)
    except ValueError:
        messagebox.showerror('Error', 'Letters only please')

window.bind('<Return>', lambda event: submit())

window.mainloop()
```

Unfortunately, this didn't work.
It kind of works? But it considers alphabets an integer, I think..
Please help.

Comment: You could test the input against [a regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6067592/regular-expression-to-match-only-alphabetic-characters)?

Comment: @AriCooper-Davis, thanks for the link and the suggestion. I had to learn about regular expressions since I've only know about them just now so yeah, and I was able to restrict my entry box input to alphabet only. Thanks!