# Spring doesn't validate JSON request

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, rest

When I send the request:

```
"Person": {
   "name": 5
 }
```

The request should fail (bad request) because 5 isn't a String. It prints: `Person{name='5'}`.

Similarly, there's no error when I send null.

I have these annotations:

```
@JsonProperty("name")
@Valid
@NotBlank
private String name;
```

Controller:

```
public void register(@Valid @RequestBody Person p) {
    ...
}
```

How can I make it validate the name so only strings are accepted?

Answer (score 0):

Add a `BindingResult` parameter.

```java
public void register(@Valid @RequestBody Person p, BindingResult result) {
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        // show error message
    }
}
```

Comment: I have nested classes and I want to validate a field in the child class. It says there are 0 errors (result.hasErrors() returns false). I put ```@Valid``` and ```@NotBlank``` on the field in the child class, and I put ```@Valid``` on the Child child; field in the Parent class. Note that it should return an error because 5 is not a String, it's a number. The person object is the child class.

Comment: @Tom1998 You may need to create your own `ObjectMapper` bean: `new ObjectMapper().disable(MapperFeature.ALLOW_COERCION_OF_SCALARS)`

Answer (score 0):

> How can I make it validate the name so only strings are accepted?

Use the `@Pattern` annotation.

```
@JsonProperty("name")
@Valid
@NotBlank
@Pattern(regexp="^[A-Za-z]*$", message = "Name should contains alphabetic values only")
private String name;
```

For more details check this [link](https://reflectoring.io/bean-validation-with-spring-boot/) and this one for the [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6067592/regular-expression-to-match-only-alphabetic-characters#:%7E:text=%5BA%2DZa%2Dz%5D%20will%20match%20all%20the%20alphabets,(both%20lowercase%20and%20uppercase).).

Comment: But this only validates a string. For example, "5" would be a valid name if I use @Pattern. Since the request from the front end has an integer 5 (not the String 5) it should fail.

Comment: Have you tried?

Comment: Yes, please see my other comment below about the parent/child classes. Person is a child class so really the request looks like ```{"Person": { "name": 5 }}```

Comment: Can you post the person object?

Comment: ```public class Person {
    @JsonProperty("name")
    @Valid
    @NotBlank(message = "failure")
    @Pattern(regexp="^[A-Za-z]*$", message = "Name should contains alphabetic values only")
    private String name;
}```

public class Parent {
    @JsonProperty("Person ")
    @Valid
    private Person person;
}