# regex for password (js)

Tags: javascript

I have a password string. I need my password to be only Latin, symbols, numbers. It doesn't have to be all together. I wrote this:

```
const pattern = /[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&*]/g;
if (!pattern.test(value)) {
    return 'ERROR';
}
```

The problem is that if I write the password: "фыва", then the validation doesn't pass the password, and if I write "фыва1", then it does. What am I doing wrong?

What regex expression should I write?

Comment: First you are missing quantifier, second characters you have provided do not match `A-Z`. Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6067592/regular-expression-to-match-only-alphabetic-characters

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to all.
This regex helped me to cope with the problem.

```
const pattern = /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]*$/;
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use this function

```
var regularExpression  = /^[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&*]$/;
```